# CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode

I was facing code singing issue while generating IPA using fastlane or xcodebuild command that was showing log like
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9DrI.png)

From xcode I keep getting prompted to unlock "Local Items" keychain on my Mac, how do I fix that?

I tried to lock and unlock key-store but that not worked

I tried to unlock keychain using below command also

security unlock-keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

90% will work.In my case that not worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Delete keychain 'login

That worked for me there might be some issue with my keychain access password

Follow these steps to prevent prompts to unlock the Local Items keychain.

1. In Finder Select Go > Go to folder (⇧⌘G)
2. In the window that appears, type the following:
   `~/Library/Keychains/`
3. Click OK.
4. Look for a folder with a name similar to this "A8F5E7B8-CEC1-4479-A7DF-F23CB076C8B8". Note: Each folder has a unique number.
5. Move this folder to the Trash.
6. Empty Trash.
7. Immediately choose Apple Menu () > Restart… to restart your Mac.
8. After restarting the computer, a new folder is created in the Keychains folder with a name similar to "4B29A0BB-599D-47FC-A2D1-42B5592B130B". This corrects the issue.

For more info: https://help.queens.edu/hc/en-us/articles/205937040-How-to-Resolve-Mac-OS-X-Keychain-Problems